# How to write a content into a file from two different files by using java.nio.files

Tags: java

I am trying to write content from two different files into a new file
But I am not getting the required result

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
public class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Path oldFile1=Paths.get("D:\\sample\\txt1.txt");
        Path oldFile2=Paths.get("D:\\sample\\txt2.txt");
        Path File=Paths.get("D:\\sample\\newFile.txt");
        Path newFile=Files.createFile(File);
        
            List<String> lines=Files.readAllLines(oldFile1);
            Files.write(newFile,lines);
          
            List<String> lines1=Files.readAllLines(oldFile2);
            Files.write(newFile,lines1);
        
    }

}
```

I tried this but newfile contains only the content of oldfile2

Comment: Read the documentation for Files.write, you'll see that there is an additional parameter to specify open options, one of which is `StandardOpenOption.APPEND`

Comment: Note it may make more sense to simply copy the raw bytes of the input files into the output file. That's essentially what you're doing already, but with an unnecessary conversion to and from strings.

Answer (score 1):

The Files.write() takes an optional parameter, which specifies the mode for opening the file. The default is CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING (Thanks @Slaw) so you are overwriting the file each time. In your case you need:

```
List<String> lines=Files.readAllLines(oldFile1);
Files.write(newFile,lines, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
          
List<String> lines1=Files.readAllLines(oldFile2);
Files.write(newFile,lines1,  StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: If no options are specified, the default is `CREATE`, `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, and `WRITE`. It's the `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` option that's causing the OP's problem. The `CREATE` option only says to create the file _if it doesn't already exist_. If the file _does_ already exist, then `CREATE` essentially does nothing.

Comment: @Slaw You're of course quite correct, a more accurate answer. Why don't you write it up as an answer, and I will delete mine?